# How to remove white space on top of my navigation bar? (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationbar, navigationcontroller

I made an apps with only using XIB (without storyboard). so to navigate I'm using this code to push some of the views:

```
let vc = SecondViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

I already make the first vc as rootvc, so it automatically created navigation bar for me.

the problem is the navigation bar generated not at top of the screen and leaving some white space gap. So here is the image when I'm using large title

[image]

and here is the normal one

[image]

I have tried to run it without safe area layout as well.
what happened is the navbar stayed there but the view goes up (through behind navbar).

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your view controller's class:

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

Try adding this line to your code for hide default navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this kind of problem, too.

There are many ways to remove white space.

I want to help you this way.

Add UIView above navigation Bar.
[image]

and then, Fix UIView Top constraint.
[image]

and change UIView Color.
[image]

this is result.

[image]

Again, there are many ways...

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you can change your status bar colour by using. i don’t  remember  the code but from here you can also can also change your colour in two Default  styles

```
//and use this to hide and show your navigation  bar 
navigationController.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```