# Large gap in navigation bar for Swift 5 / Xcode

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uikit, uinavigationbar

I have a very large white gap in my navigation bar. I'm using programmatic auto layout, not swiftUI. I tried setting

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.setNeedsLayout()
```

But I'm getting the same results.

All of the previous solutions have not worked.

[image of the gap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIiT9.png)

Any ideas? Thank you.

```
func configureUI() {
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "slapText.png"))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    navigationItem.titleView = imageView
    imageView.setDimensions(width: 32, height: 16)
    
    let trending = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "TrendingWhite.png"))
    trending.setDimensions(width: 32, height: 32)
    
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.cornerRadius = 10
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.clipsToBounds = true
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: trending)
        
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMaxYCorner, .layerMaxXMaxYCorner]
    //changes "The Slap" color to user selected color
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .purple
    imageView.image = imageView.image?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    imageView.tintColor = UIColor.white
}
```

Adding

```
navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
```

removes the entire navigation bar

Comment: maybe this is helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70287439/how-to-remove-white-space-on-top-of-my-navigation-bar-swift

Comment: @tail thank you for the link but they just added a color to make the gap look like it's not there, rather than remove the gap.